I got ModuleNotFoundError and ImportError in importing pyreadstat (no error in installing in terminal)
I am learning python, and have a trouble installing pyreadstat. I could find many folks has same issue, and tried to follow the answers in them, these did not work for me as well. Therefore, I am reporting my things and hope to get your help.
I think this link was quite similar to my thing. But three suggestions seem not working on my environment.
I am using Jupyter Notebook in VScode, mac.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

raw_welfare = pd.read_spss('Files/Koweps_hpwc14_2019_beta2.sav')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py:135, in import_optional_dependency(name, extra, errors, min_version)
    134 try:
--> 135     module = importlib.import_module(name)
    136 except ImportError:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1206, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1178, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyreadstat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 raw_welfare = pd.read_spss('Files/Koweps_hpwc14_2019_beta2.sav')
...
--> 138         raise ImportError(msg)
    139     return None
    141 # Handle submodules: if we have submodule, grab parent module from sys.modules

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'pyreadstat'.  Use pip or conda to install pyreadstat.
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

In the explorer, my file is in "myenv" folder, and when I install pyreadstat in terminal (bash), it does not show error. "pip list" in terminal, it shows pyreadstat as verion 1.2.7.
"which pip" in terminal, it puts as "~~~~/Python/myenv/bin/pip" ('Python' is where my code file placed).
When I searched the folder for pyreadstat, it was in "~~~/Python/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyreadstat" and, site-packages folder has pip, pandas, numpy folders which works well in my mac.
Some other folks' help, did not work as well.
conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat

I hope my information was useful for your help. Thank you for your help in advance.
Best,
Simon

In the notebook where you want to import it, run %pip list and it will show what the kernel can see. The terminal is not necessarily connected to the environment the active kernel is using. If you don't have conda involved then you may be able to use the magic install command %pip install pyreadstat run in a new cell in the notebook where you want to import it. Run that in the notebook and then restart the kernel and try the import statement to see if it works. If it is a very complex install, you'll need to refresh your browser for it to work fully. It can be best to restart everything.

 (Minor: I'm assuming you don't have conda involved since you said it didn't work, but that is a big assumption as your description of a lot of of this is very vague. Next time use specifics and don't bring up things unless they are involved are you specify clearly how it didn't work. For example here, I would hope running conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat would say something about conda being a command. And so that is why it would fail and the type of details you should have included if you want to fully describe things best in a post.)

 I should have said above about the magic install command to see more about the modern %pip install command here.

Wayne, THANK YOU for the magic :) and I found that opening sav file works in other notebook as well. I thought that I provided much information, but I will try to specify my stuff clearly. Thanks!

try restarting the kernel, maybe this is the problem

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
